# How Count Occurrences of RegEx with AMPScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

How do we count the number of regex occurrences in a string?

If we knew the exact phrase then we could do something like the below:

`(LEN(Text Area) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(Text Area),"dog","")))/3`

However i don't have an exact phrase. I have something like this:

```
pattern: <0>some text</0>,<1>some text</1>,<2>some text</2>...<n>some text</n>
Sample string:You are <0>awesome</0> and I want to <1>thank you</1>.
Regex: <\/?([0-9]+)>
```

I want the regex to validate that each `n` tag has an opening and closing tag and i want the total number of tags.

If this was JS, it would be easy but if there a built in function in AMPScript or anything that could be used to achieve this?

The challenge i have isn't with the regex itself, it with the fact that there's no while loop. Is there anyway to get "count of occurrences back"?

Comment: I do not believe so and honestly even if there was, I get the feeling it would be convoluted and complex. Why would you shy away from using SSJS instead for this aspect? I do not foresee a huge increase in the processing time for adding this in and you can pass the values back and forth between AMPscript and SSJS so you do not necessarily need to stick to a single language if you don't want to.

Comment: I switched to SSJS after spending 2 days trying to work out an AMP solution. It was recommended to use AMP only but at this point i have come to same conclusion that it's not possible.

Comment: yeah AMPscript is limited and honestly although it is 'best practice' to use only AMPscript - honestly SSJS is just as viable and sometimes even better than AMPscript depending on needs and context.